# Django - Increase FileField length

Tags: django

I'm trying to store a file using a FileField, but the path of the destination of the file is larger than 100 characters. How can I increase the number of allowed characters? I've tried with max_length=255 but didn't work.

Thanks.

Edit: Added model

```
class File(models.Model):
    Record = models.ForeignKey(Records)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files/Records', blank=False)
    Upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Title
```

Comment: show your model code please

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Django documentation makes it clear that the `FileField` takes an optional argument to alter the length of the varchar column used to store the file reference (filename).

[Taken from the Django documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield):

> FileField instances are created in your database as varchar columns with a default max length of 100 characters. As with other fields, you can change the maximum length using the max_length argument.

In order to make use of this `max_length` parameter, you simply add the parameter into the model's field declaration, like so:

```
class File(models.Model):
    Record = models.ForeignKey(Records)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    File = models.FileField(upload_to='files/Records', blank=False, max_length=500)
    Upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.Title
```

The `max_length` of the `FileField` provided by Django is enforced at the database level. When you make a change to the model definition which must be enforced at the database level, you may find that you must use the `syncdb` or a migration in order to effect this change in the database. Simply changing the `max_length` parameter in your model definition will have no effect, unless you then migrate your database to also reflect this change.

In this particular case, the varchar column that represents the reference filename to the file stored in the `FileField` must be updated to allow filenames of greater length. Please be sure that you have done the necessary database maintenance to ensure that your model's fields are faithfully represented in your database. More information about migrations can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/).

Comment: It's strange. I'd proved with max_length before but didn't work. Now works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: In case anyone has a similar use-case to mine ... I have a document meta data model and an associated file model. I thought this error was tied to my document model's name field. I verified it did indeed have a max_size of 260 or so but as pointed out here, it was on the file model's filefield. Setting max_length to 260 here seems to work well for my situation.

Answer (score 5):

I think your code was cool if you added max_length=255 to FileField, only you forgot to update it in your database (makemigrations -> migrate)