# value too long for type character varying(100)----recently switched database, didn't do anything in db

Tags: django, postgresql

I recently switched to postgresql, I thought everything worked fine until I realized when I make post I get value too long for type character varying(100). Now I googled it, and saw some similar questions but when I tried some solutions there none of them worked. I will explain why my question is different in my opinion. I have this code in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    objects = models.Manager()    

@property

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=255)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As I saw some recommended solutions, I did try changing my max_length to 100. I have no idea why this is happening, I don't have anything in db. I recently switched to postgresql. Can you help me why this error is occurring and how I can fix it? should I move away from uuslug?

Full model

```
.
class Category(models.Model): 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name=('describe'))
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%s/" %self.name

def my_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    action.send(instance.author, verb='following', target=Category)
post_save.connect(my_handler, sender=Category)


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=('community'))
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    video = EmbedVideoField(verbose_name='link',help_text="Youtube", blank=True, null=True) 

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    objects = models.Manager()            # default manager
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default= 1)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)


    @property
    def domain(self):
        long_url = urlparse(self.url).netloc if self.url else "be kind to one another"
        return long_url.split('.', 1)[1] if long_url.split('.', 1)[0] == 'www' else long_url
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self, max_length=255)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here's full Traceback

T

```
raceback:
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "ebagu/main/views.py" in dispatch
  191.      return super(PostCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)       
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  249.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  215.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "ebagu/main/views.py" in form_valid
  186.          self.object.save()
File "ebagu/main/models.py" in save
  66.       super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  734.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  762.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  846.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  885.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  920.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  974.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: DataError at /add_post/
Exception Value: value too long for type character varying(100)
```

Comment: you have a SlugField without predefined length? Set it to 255 and migrate

Comment: I dont see any field with `max_length=100` in your code, so I suspect you are not showing all/relevant code. Anyway, the problem is following (as you probably find by googling) - when you save too long value in MySQL, it will just trim the value without telling you, so you can get crippled data as a result. PgSQL will loudly die instead. So you have to find which field has the limit of 100 characters, and trim the data accordingly, or increase the limit as @MushahidKhan suggested in the comment above

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I don't have any field that has the limit of 100 characters. I'll post my full model

Comment: Show the error traceback please

Comment: @chem1st I have added the traceback....really hope this problem gets fixed

Comment: @winixxee of course you do - `ImageField` (and many others) have `max_length=100` as the default value

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko oh the default is set to 100 then?because I didn't set it manually, what should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: What would you say? You need to make sure the values you save in the fields are not longer than `max_length` (I'd recommend to make the sanitization in `save()`), and you can combine it with the advice from 1st comment by @MushahidKhan

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko so set everything to 255?and the default ones that I didn't set are automatically set to 100?hmm that's the first time I heard this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you need help fixing this problem, so much as you need help debugging it. Once the problem is clear, the solution seems clear as well. The Traceback is perhaps a bit unclear because it's going through so much Django source code and it's not telling you which of your fields is having an issue.

**Background To This Issue**

To start with, we're having problems saving a `Post` instance. Well, look at all of these fields you have in your model definition:

```
 ...
  url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
  video = EmbedVideoField(verbose_name='link',help_text="Youtube", blank=True, null=True) 
  content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images',blank=True, null=True)
  thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

These may not *look like* text fields, but a lot of them are variations on text fields because, if you think about it, you're probably not going to store *whole files* in your database. What you will do instead (and what Django does by default) is store the file somewhere on some disk and then in the database you would store the *path* to that file so you can retrieve it when you need to.

Further, it's probably a waste to store file-paths in the db as `LongText` or whatever, so every `FileField` we have means we've got a field with a `max_length` whether we specify it or not. Thus, all of the above fields have an implicit `max_length`. You can actually find this out by reading the Django source code.

**Source Examples**

I've never used `EmbedVideoField`, for example, but it turns out to be [a subclass of `models.URLField`](https://github.com/yetty/django-embed-video/blob/master/embed_video/fields.py#L12), which means it has a `max_length` by default [set to 200](https://github.com/django/django/blob/004ba0f99eb25c3f32aa3a41707534e955d1878e/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L2336) if you do not specify one.

Moreover, your various `ImageField`s are just subclasses of `FileField`, [which has a `max_length` default of 100](https://github.com/django/django/blob/16411b8400ad08f90c236bb2e18f65c655f903f8/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L234).

**How to Debug Problems Like This In the Future?**

Now, this doesn't help us to know *which* of your fields is throwing an error in this case. For that, I would probably set a breakpoint somewhere in the code, probably here:

```
File "ebagu/main/models.py" in save
   66.       super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

By "set a breakpoint", I mean the following:

Go to line 65 in the module mentioned above, `ebagu/main/models.py` and enter the following and save the module: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

(I actually have a strong preference for [ipdb](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/11/18/intro-python-debugger/) myself, but that requires Ipython, which I also have a strong preference for...)

Run your local server, and run through the steps that produced this issue. You will end up submitting your form and if you look at the console where you started your server, you'll eventually be dumped into a shell right at line 65. This shell is a [pdb shell](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), which has different rules from a normal shell, but you can evaluate your about-to-be-saved `Post` instance, by looking at the various fields on the instance itself, `self`, and running Python code in the context of that method call:

```
(pdb) len(self.image.path)
```

Using that, I would manually evaluate the various fields and look at which one has this really long entry that is choking the save (probably one of your `ImageField`s).

**Solution with Warnings**

Alternately, you can just add a `max_length` to all of these, but be forewarned that you will most likely need to perform **database migrations** for any limited text field you change because your database is still going to verify the length of the input against how the column is defined. [Here's a good StackOverflow answer looking at exactly this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580570/1748754).

**Footnote**

Why didn't this come up before you switched to Postgresql? There are a variety of potential reasons, but it probably has to do with how the previous database was setup vs how the Postgresql database was set up (manually vs Django migrations?).

It may also have to do with whether or not you changed where these things are being stored. Did you change your `MEDIA` settings so the paths where files are stored got a lot longer?

What you really should be doing is looking directly at your database. Open up a `psql` instance and ask it to describe your tables for you. It'll tell you which fields are limited to 100 characters and those are the fields giving you problems.

Comment: thank you for getting back to you so late, I was about to deploy my app that I switched to postgresql but I'm having some problem with my project that I went back to sqlite. if you have time, and look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669918/function-notifies-commentor-when-the-poster-should-get-notified I would be really appreciated

Comment: Honestly, I think you need some help debugging your code. That's why I wrote this the way I did. It's not going to work to have stackoverflow debug your whole application.

Comment: yes this is my first project, and when I was reading your solution I was thinking "what does he mean by debugging, everything is working so far" , I heard how important debugging is but just don't get the grasp. every thing seems to work...ofc this is from a noobie...

Answer (score 3):

Look into database.

---

**Quick psql tutorial**

Start postgres client shell, eg. with `python manage.py dbshell`. Something like this shows:

```
ebagu=>
```

The lines

```
File "ebagu/main/models.py" in save
  66.       super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

show you are trying to save model **Post** in what I assume is app **main**. If you didn't change table in Post's Meta, the table should be something like `main_post`.

You want to display all tables in postgres shell with command:

```
\d
```

It will list tables in a similar fashion:

```
                          List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |     Type      | Owner  
--------+-----------------------------------+---------------+--------
 public | django_migrations                 | table         | hruske
 public | django_migrations_id_seq          | sequence      | hruske
 public | django_session                    | table         | hruske
```

If you want to check the details of the table `django_session` you can do:

```
\d django_session
```

And you get something like this:

```
             Table "public.django_session"
    Column    |           Type           | Modifiers 
--------------+--------------------------+-----------
 session_key  | character varying(40)    | not null
 session_data | text                     | not null
 expire_date  | timestamp with time zone | not null
Indexes:
    "django_session_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (session_key)
    "django_session_de54fa62" btree (expire_date)
    "django_session_session_key_461cfeaa630ca218_like" btree (session_key varchar_pattern_ops)
```

Here you can see which fields are defined as `varchar(100)`.

If you want to know more psql commands, type `\?`

Answer (score 0):

Removing the migration files from previous database should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to already saved data in your database being longer than the given characters. You may want to look at the data and consider fixing it or whether the given characters are really the limit you want.

If you are maintaining history for model than you also need to delete data in history table.