# exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not HttpResponseRedirect

Tags: python, django

What does this error mean? I'm importing `from django.shortcuts import render, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect`
but why can;t I use HttpResponseRedirect? I read traceback, but nothing useful there...
here's my code

```
@login_required
def read(request, id):
    try:
        next = request.GET.get('next', None)
        notification = Notification.objects.get(id=id)
        if notification.recipient == request.user:
            notification.read = True
            notification.save()
            if next is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
        else:
            raise Http404
    except:
        raise HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
```

I don't understand what the error means, can some one explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line:

```
except:
    raise HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
```

The traceback is telling you that you cannot `raise HttpResponseRedirect(...)` because that's not an `Exception` that has inherited from `BaseException`.

What you probably wanted to do was use `return` here instead or alternate raise a 404 instead?

Comment: by the way, do you mind taking a look at this?stackoverflow.com/questions/35478137/… I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: I gave it a shot. I think the Traceback is throwing you off a bit because the messaging is not too informative. In general,  you should work on reading Tracebacks more closely and by that I mean, the whole things. Look for places in your application where the errors occur. Python has beautiful and useful Tracebacks.

Answer (score 1):

HttpResponseRedirect is not an exception, but a django function that returns a redirect.

Since it can be confusing, you might want to use render instead:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

...

     if next is not None:
       return redirect(next)
     else:
       return redirect(reverse("notifications_all"))
```

Comment: by the way, do you mind taking a look at this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478137/value-too-long-for-type-character-varying100-recently-switched-database-di I've been struggling with this for a while...

Comment: hey. I'm on MySQL, sorry