# Function notifies commentor when the poster should get notified

Tags: python, django

If I comment on the post named "a", then I get a notification saying that I made the comment on "a" but the notification system should notify the user who created post "a".

I have a clue what to do, because I have done something similar (notifying the user who commented when there's a reply to that comment) thanks to some tutorial.

In models.py for notification, I have to send the right notification and connect to it. I'll post my full code, you can see the bottom function for the connecting, and this is the one I'm having problem with.

```
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey, GenericRelation
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    from main.models import Post
    from accounts.models import MyProfile
    from .signals import notify
    # Create your models here.

    class NotificationQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
        def get_user(self, recipient):
            return self.filter(recipient=recipient)

        def mark_targetless(self, recipient):
            qs = self.unread().get_user(recipient)
            qs_no_target = qs.filter(target_object_id=None)
            if qs_no_target:
                qs_no_target.update(read=True)

        def mark_all_read(self, recipient):
            qs = self.unread().get_user(recipient)
            qs.update(read=True)

        def mark_all_unread(self, recipient):
            qs = self.read().get_user(recipient)
            qs.update(read=False)

        def unread(self):
            return self.filter(read=False)

        def read(self):
            return self.filter(read=True)

        def recent(self):
            return self.unread()[:5]


    class NotificationManager(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return NotificationQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

        def all_unread(self, user):
            return self.get_queryset().get_user(user).unread()

        def all_read(self, user):
            return self.get_queryset().get_user(user).read()

        def all_for_user(self, user):
            self.get_queryset().mark_targetless(user)
            return self.get_queryset().get_user(user)


    class Notification(models.Model):
        sender_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='nofity_sender')
        sender_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        sender_object = GenericForeignKey("sender_content_type", "sender_object_id")

        verb = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        action_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='notify_action', 
            null=True, blank=True)
        action_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        action_object = GenericForeignKey("action_content_type", "action_object_id")

        target_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, related_name='notify_target', 
            null=True, blank=True)
        target_object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
        target_object = GenericForeignKey("target_content_type", "target_object_id")

        recipient = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE, related_name='notifications')
        read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

        objects = NotificationManager()



        def __unicode__(self):
            try:
                target_url = self.target_object.get_absolute_url()
            except:
                target_url = None
            context = {
                "sender": self.sender_object,
                "verb": self.verb,
                "action": self.action_object,
                "target": self.target_object,
                "verify_read": reverse("notifications_read", kwargs={"id": self.id}),
                "target_url": target_url,
            }
            if self.target_object:
                if self.action_object and target_url:
                    return "%(sender)s %(verb)s <a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(target)s</a> with %(action)s" %context
                if self.action_object and not target_url:
                    return "%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s" %context
                return "%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s" %context
            return "%(sender)s %(verb)s" %context

        @property   
        def get_link(self):
            try:
                target_url = self.target_object.get_absolute_url()
            except:
                target_url = reverse("notifications_all")

            context = {
                "sender": self.sender_object,
                "verb": self.verb,
                "action": self.action_object,
                "target": self.target_object,
                "verify_read": reverse("notifications_read", kwargs={"id": self.id}),
                "target_url": target_url,
            }
            if self.target_object:
                return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s %(target)s with %(action)s</a>" %context
            else:
                return "<a href='%(verify_read)s?next=%(target_url)s'>%(sender)s %(verb)s</a>" %context


    def new_notification(sender, **kwargs):
        kwargs.pop('signal', None)
        recipient = kwargs.pop("recipient")
        verb = kwargs.pop("verb")
        affected_users = kwargs.pop('affected_users')

        #super_user_qs = MyProfile.objects.get(user=Post.moderator), 
    ''' this is wrong, It;s what I tried but failed
        if super_user_qs:
             super_user_instance = super_user_qs
             new_note = Notification(
                    recipient=super_user_instance,
                    verb = verb, # smart_text
                    sender_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender),
                    sender_object_id = sender.id,
                    )
             for option in ("target", "action"):
                    obj = kwargs.pop(option, None)
                    if obj is not None:
                        setattr(new_note, "%s_content_type" %option, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))
                        setattr(new_note, "%s_object_id" %option, obj.id)
             new_note.save()

  the below works for notifying commentor who gets reply
  '''    
        if affected_users is not None:
            for u in affected_users:
                if u == sender:
                    pass
                else:
                    new_note = Notification(
                        recipient=recipient,
                        verb = verb, # smart_text
                        sender_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender),
                        sender_object_id = sender.id,
                        )
                    for option in ("target", "action"):
                        try:
                            obj = kwargs[option]
                            if obj is not None:
                                setattr(new_note, "%s_content_type" %option, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))
                                setattr(new_note, "%s_object_id" %option, obj.id)
                        except:
                            pass
                    new_note.save()
        else:
            new_note = Notification(
                recipient=recipient,
                verb = verb, # smart_text
                sender_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender),
                sender_object_id = sender.id,
                )
            for option in ("target", "action"):
                obj = kwargs.pop(option, None)
                if obj is not None:
                    setattr(new_note, "%s_content_type" %option, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))
                    setattr(new_note, "%s_object_id" %option, obj.id)
            new_note.save()


    notify.connect(new_notification)
```

And then in models.py I have comment and post models. the get_affected_user is the function that's used in comment views.py to notify affected_user I believe. (I followed a tutorial.)

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
    @property 
    def get_origin(self):
        return self.path

    @property
    def get_comment(self):
        return self.text

    @property
    def is_child(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def get_children(self):
        if self.is_child:
            return None
        else:
            return Comment.objects.filter(parent=self)

    def get_affected_users(self):
        """ 
        it needs to be a parent and have children, 
        the children, in effect, are the affected users.
        """
        comment_children = self.get_children()
        if comment_children is not None:
            users = []
            for comment in comment_children:
                if comment.user in users:
                    pass
                else:
                    users.append(comment.user)
            return users
        return None



class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

In views.py for comment, the above get_affected_user is used for notifying commentor who gets reply. I thought about using the same function to achieve what I want, but couldn't. So for that I just set get_affected_user to none for now.

```
def comment_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')
        post_id = request.POST.get("post_id")
        origin_path = request.POST.get("origin_path")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None

        parent_comment = None
        if parent_id is not None:
            try:
                parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)
            except:
                parent_comment = None

            if parent_comment is not None and parent_comment.post is not None:
                post = parent_comment.post

        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment_text = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            if parent_comment is not None:
                # parent comments exists
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=parent_comment.get_origin, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post,
                    parent=parent_comment
                    )
                #affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                #print "this is"
                affected_users = parent_comment.get_affected_users()
                notify.send(
                        MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                        action=new_comment, 
                        target=parent_comment, 
                        recipient=parent_comment.user,
                        affected_users = affected_users,
                        verb='replied to')
                messages.success(request, "Thank you for your response.", extra_tags='safe')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(parent_comment.get_absolute_url())
            else:
                new_comment = Comment.objects.create_comment(
                    user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
                    path=origin_path, 
                    text=comment_text,
                    post = post
                    )
                notify.send(
                        MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                        recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user), 
                        action=new_comment, 
                        affected_users = None,
                        target = new_comment.post,
                        verb='commented on')
                messages.success(request, "Thank you for the comment.")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            messages.error(request, "There was an error with your comment.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(origin_path)

    else:
        raise Http404
```

Edit:I'm having this problem for almost a week now.....I asked for some help from the instructor of the tutorial I purchased, and he only answers in short sentences(I can tell he doesn't absolutely care). Here are some hints he dropped. If I were to notify superuser 
I should add the following to the models.py for notification,

```
super_user_qs = User.objects.filter(is_admin=True)
if super_user_qs.exists():
     super_user_instance = super_user_qs.first()
     new_note = Notification(
            recipient=super_user_instance,
            verb = verb, # smart_text
            sender_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(sender),
            sender_object_id = sender.id,
            )
      for option in ("target", "action"):
            obj = kwargs.pop(option, None)
            if obj is not None:
                setattr(new_note, "%s_content_type" %option, ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj))
                setattr(new_note, "%s_object_id" %option, obj.id)
      new_note.save()
```

but then I told him, I'm trying to notify post creator/moderator because any one can make post.(I told him this couple times/before he answered with the superuser one) I should use model post_save signal to create a new Notification within the model I'm working on. and I do not have to use the custom notify signal in this case.

Meanwhile, I was watching the tutorials over and over. I thought maybe I just need to change                        recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=post.moderator), 
to the post.moderator but then I get Cannot assign "": "Notification.recipient" must be a "MyProfile" instance. so I did                         recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=post.moderator), but this notify to me about the comments I make...

I really await any advise
thank you

Comment: Full error message please.

Comment: Before downvoting my answer, look at the edit history. I was answering the initial question.

Comment: @alecxe, hello it was probably my fault for not clarifying it. your answer shows the notification about the comment I make...I appreciate your help but it doesn't work

Comment: @alecxe please help me as I appreciate any help ;)

Comment: You still haven't included an error message / stack trace...

Comment: What is you `notify.send` actually doing ? Is that sending the actual notification? Also, here is my understanding of the problem you are trying to solve: `it looks like, when someone is replying to a comment, both the commentor, and the person who originally commented should get notified.` - Does this sound correct?

Comment: @karthikr, hello thank you for the comment. notify.send is sending the notification to the recipient. ultimate goal I'm trying to achieve is to send notification to the user who made the post when some other user commented on that post

Comment: I think the notfiication should be sent to `recipient = new_comment.post.moderator.get_profile()` instead of `recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)` This would send the notification to the moderator of the Post..

Comment: @karthikr yes thank you, can you post that as an answer so I can give you the bounty

Comment: @winixxee Sure - I also think there are lots of places in your code that could be simplified/refactored. I will try and create a gist and share the link with you to basically simplify the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to notify the POST owner, it should be sent this way:

```
recipient = new_comment.post.moderator
```

instead of

```
recipient = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

This would send the notification to the moderator of the Post.

Comment: hello I think this is the right solution but I get 'User' object has no attribute 'get_profile' which I used to "     user=MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user),
" instead of request.user to avoid

Comment: This was based on your models.. There might be a few changes to actually get it to work, but the idea is, you need to send the email address of the moderator on the `POST` object instead of the current users' profile.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it is:

`if parent_comment is not None:` This line evaluates to false, so the recipient of the message is `request.user`.

You should make sure that this line `parent_id = request.POST.get('parent_id')` has a meaningful value

This line `parent_comment = Comment.objects.get(id=parent_id)` might be the culprit. Insert a `print('!!!!!parent_id = ', parent_id)` after this line, and see if you get in the console the id of an actual comment.

But that's what I suspect anyway, that the templates you created don't include this field in the form.

If you paste the template code, I might be able to help you debug.