# Creating a function to Specify Directory for Uploaded Images Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have created a function for my items model where there are images to be uploaded according to the name of the user and the title of the item.

Now I am trying to add more images to this item and there is a foreign key with the image, but now instead of creating randomly uploading the new images to another folder, I want to upload these images to the same folder that was previously determined according to the same item.

I have tried to alter the previous function but it returned with an error `upload_design_to() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` I assume because i didn't add `self` to the function but I don't know what to replace it with.

The functions below will be more descriptive:

Here is the models and the function where the images is uploaded to a location as per the users name and the title of the item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    def upload_design_to(self, filename):
        return f'{self.designer}/{self.title}/{filename}'

    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=upload_design_to)
```

Now I have created a new an Image model to add more images to this item and want them to be uploaded to the very same folder

```
class Images(models.Model):
    def upload_design_to(filename):
        return f'{Item.designer}/{Item.title}/{filename}'
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: `upload_design_to` should have `self` as the first argument? You should use `{self.item.designer}` in your string too probably

Comment: @IainShelvington it `returned Storage can not find an available filename for "<django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ForwardManyToOneDescriptor object at 0x03E26100>\<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x03E26178>\project_Design_2_mdnSA2w.JPG". Please make sure that the corresponding file field allows sufficient "max_length".`

Comment: You've not added `self.` to the format string have you? It looks like you're still using `Item.` which is using the field descriptors on that model. crimsonpython24's answer below looks correct

Comment: @IainShelvington your answer is correct if you want to post it as an answer

Comment: posted an answer that is probably a slight improvement on my previous comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution where you don't repeat yourself would be to call the `upload_design_to` of the related `Item`

```
class Images(models.Model):
    def upload_design_to(self, filename):
        return self.item.upload_design_to(filename)

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=upload_design_to)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
class Images(models.Model):
    def upload_design_to(self, filename):
        return f'{self.item.designer}/{self.item.title}/{filename}'

    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=upload_design_to)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

About the error that you raised, you can also set a `max_length` attribute to your filefield so that it doesn't go over the file limit. You can just set this to 10000000 or something that is long enough for your file. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26580570)

Comment: The method should go before the field so that you don't get `NameError: name 'upload_design_to' is not defined`